# Get only the line of text that contains the given word VB2010.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file on my website and I download the whole string via webclient.downloadstring.

The text file contains this :

cookies,dishes,candy,(new line)
back,forward,refresh,(new line)
mail,media,mute,

This is just an example it's not the actual string , but it will do for help purposes.

What I want is I want to download the whole string , find the line that contains the word that was entered by the user in a `textbox`, get that line into a string, then I want to use the string.split with as delimiter the "," and output each word that is in the string into an `richtextbox`.

Now here is the code that I have used (some fields are removed for privacy reasons).

```
If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
        words = web.DownloadString("webadress here")
        If words.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
            'retrieval code here
            Dim length As Integer = TextBox1.TextLength
            Dim word As String
            word = words.Substring(length + 1) // the plus 1 is for the ","
            Dim cred() As String
            cred = word.Split(",")
            RichTextBox1.Text = "Your word: " + cred(0) + vbCr + "Your other word: " + cred(1)
        Else
            MsgBox("Sorry, but we could not find the word you have entered", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Please fill in an word", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If
```

Now it works and no errors , but it only works for line 1 and not on line 2 or 3

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the string `words` also contains the new line characters that you seem to be omitting in your code. You should first split `words` with the delimiter `\n` (or `\r\n`, depending on the platform), like this:

```
Dim lines() As String = words.Split("\n")
```

After that, you have an array of strings, each element representing a single line. Loop it through like this:

```
For Each line As String In lines
    If line.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
        'retrieval code here
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Smi's answer is correct, but since you're using VB you need to split on vbNewLine. \n and \r are for use in C#.  I get tripped up by that a lot.

Another way to do this is to use regular expressions.  A regular expression match can both find the word you want and return the line that contains it in a single step.

Barely tested sample below. I couldn't quite figure out if your code was doing what you said it should be doing so I improvised based on your description.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub ButtonFind_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonFind.Click

        Dim downloadedString As String
        downloadedString = "cookies,dishes,candy," _
             & vbNewLine & "back,forward,refresh," _
             & vbNewLine & "mail,media,mute,"

        'Use the regular expression anchor characters (^$) to match a line that contains the given text.
        Dim wordToFind As String = TextBox1.Text & ","  'Include the comma that comes after each word to avoid partial matches.
        Dim pattern As String = "^.*" & wordToFind & ".*$"
        Dim rx As Regex = New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline + RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        Dim M As Match = rx.Match(downloadedString)
        'M will either be Match.Empty (no matching word was found), 
        'or it will be the matching line.

        If M IsNot Match.Empty Then
            Dim words() As String = M.Value.Split(","c)
            RichTextBox1.Clear()
            For Each word As String In words
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(word) Then
                    RichTextBox1.AppendText(word & vbNewLine)
                End If
            Next
        Else
            RichTextBox1.Text = "No match found."
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```